# onBackPressed() Method is not working with bottomNavigationView while using Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I have used BottomNavigationView With Navigation component, back button is working fine when i switched between navigation items (i.e. Recents, Nearby etc tabs)
[Check out the image for clearification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOhRF.png)

But Back Button is not working when i open an app and don't switch between navigation items and directly press back button in order to close the app.

**Let me explain my problem in details**

*1. Take a scenario where back button is working fine*

When i open the app and click on any BottomNavigationView items (i.e Recents, Favorites, Nearby tabs) and after this when i press back button, the back button is working fine it goes to initial tab i.e. Recents tab and again press back button the app is close. This scenario is okay

*2 Take second scenario where back button is not working*

When i open the app and don't switch between tabs of bottomNavigationView (i.e. Recents tab etc) and press back button then the back button is not working,Now how to resolve this issue.

Here is the code of BottomNavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav_view"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_tab_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_tab_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Inactive"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

And Kotlin Code

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
   
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostHomeFragment)

        //attaching bottom navigation view with nav host fragment
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navHostHomeFragment.findNavController())

        //When Nav Controller destination change then getting current fragment label and set that label to toolbar textview
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
            tvHomeToolbar.text = destination.label
        }


    }

    override fun onNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
    
}
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.home.HomeActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHomeToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_font_semibold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineSeparatorTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:background="@color/color_gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostHomeFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lineSeparatorTop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/lineSeparatorBottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineSeparatorBottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:background="@color/color_gray"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav_view"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_tab_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_tab_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Inactive"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include your `R.layout.activity_home` XML file? Just to clarify, the 'back button' you're talking about is the system back button on the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen and not the Up button on your Toolbar?

Comment: I'm talking about system back button

Comment: Is your recents screen the `startDestination` of your graph? Or do you have some other start destination? If so, what is that start destination and how do you go from that screen to one of your bottom nav items?

Comment: Yes, recents screen is the `startDestination` of my graph